# How to align a caption to the left side of a table in an wrapped environment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions, floatrow

I am trying to find a solution for the following problem:

I have a table in a wrapped environment (wraptable). I need my table caption to be left aligned with the table. Also, I don't want the caption to exceed the length of the table itself.
Right now the result looks like this:

[image]

In an online forum I found a solution using the floatrow package. However this did not quite work, as the result looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

My MWE (I am sorry. I know this isn't really "minimal". But I wasn't sure which packages were ok to delete for the MWE to still work.)

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage, a4paper, oneside, headsepline]{scrreprt} % headsepline 



\usepackage{scrhack} % verbessert einige Fremdpakete und das Zusammenspiel von einigen Paketen mit KOMA-Script
\usepackage{graphicx} % Graphiken einfügen
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Text fließt um Figure
\usepackage{caption} % Überschriften formatieren
\usepackage{booktabs} % Tabelle
\usepackage[section]{placeins} %Floatbarriere

\usepackage{multirow} %für Tabellen
\usepackage{makecell} %fette hline
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption} %Tabellencaption linksbündig
% \usepackage{floatrow} % Tabellencaption in wrapped umgebung

\usepackage{threeparttable} %Tabellenüberschrift linksbündig an Tabelle

\usepackage{caption} % doopelte hline
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\doubleRule{\toprule\toprule}
\newcommand\doublerule{\toprule\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{\doublerulesep}{0.95em}}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mytabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[mytabitem]{nosep,leftmargin=*,before=\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip},after=\vspace{-1\baselineskip}, label=\textbullet}
\newcommand{\tabitem}[1]{\begin{mytabitem}\item #1\end{mytabitem}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{makecell}


\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
```

My table:

```
\begin{wraptable}{r}{0.7\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7} % this reduces the vertical spacing between rows
\linespread{0.95} \selectfont \centering
% \ttabbox
\caption{Perceived family influence on organizational identity}
\label{table:Perceived family influence on organizational identity}


\begin{tabular}{p{4cm} p{2.5cm}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{~} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Interviewees}\\
\midrule
\vtop{\hbox{\strut Family influence as most important}\hbox{\strut factor influencing OI}} & [14], [15] \\
\vtop{\hbox{\strut Family influence has great impact}\hbox{\strut on OI}} & [] \\
\vtop{\hbox{\strut Family influence can have impact}\hbox{\strut on OI}} & [] \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{wraptable}
```

Thank you for your help!

Lea

Comment: You need to match the width  of the wraptable to the width of the tabular.

Comment: Regarding: "But I wasn't sure which packages were ok to delete for the MWE to still work.": Comment out a package, recompile and see if the document still results in teh issue you describe. If it does, the package is not related.

Comment: Also, you might want to go through your preamble and delete packages that you load more than once.

Comment: [14]  and [15]  in the second column of your table seem to be numbers pointing to entries in a bibliography. Instead of inserting them manually, I hope you use a bibliography management related package such as `biblatex`. If you do not yet use such a package, please do yourself the favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you aready seem to know about the `threeparttable` package and one of its features (`\usepackage{threeparttable} %Tabellenüberschrift linksbündig an Tabelle`), why not use it?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage, a4paper, oneside, headsepline]{scrreprt} % headsepline 

\usepackage{wrapfig} % Text fließt um Figure

\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption} %Tabellencaption linksbündig
\usepackage{threeparttable} %Tabellenüberschrift linksbündig an Tabelle
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum} % For filler text. Don't use in actual document.


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]

\begin{wraptable}{r}{0.7\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7} % this reduces the vertical spacing between rows
\linespread{0.95} \selectfont \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Perceived family influence on organizational identity}
\label{table:Perceived family influence on organizational identity}
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm} p{2.5cm}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{~} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Interviewees}\\
\midrule
\vtop{\hbox{\strut Family influence as most important}\hbox{\strut factor influencing OI}} & [14], [15] \\
\vtop{\hbox{\strut Family influence has great impact}\hbox{\strut on OI}} & [] \\
\vtop{\hbox{\strut Family influence can have impact}\hbox{\strut on OI}} & [] \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{wraptable}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

---

Since the code of your table is quite cluttered with all the basically superfluous `\hbox` commands, I'd suggest one of the following approaches instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage, a4paper, oneside, headsepline]{scrreprt} % headsepline 

\usepackage{wrapfig} % Text fließt um Figure

\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption} %Tabellencaption linksbündig
\usepackage{threeparttable} %Tabellenüberschrift linksbündig an Tabelle
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum} % For filler text. Don't use in actual document.
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{wraptable}{r}{0.7\textwidth}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Perceived family influence on organizational identity}
    \label{table:Perceived family influence on organizational identity}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{6.5cm} p{2.5cm}}
      \toprule 
        & Interviewees \\
      \midrule
      Family influence as most important factor influencing OI & [14], [15] \\
      Family influence has great impact \newline on OI & [] \\
      Family influence can have impact \newline on OI & [] \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{wraptable}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{wraptable}{r}{0.7\textwidth}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Perceived family influence on organizational identity}
    \label{table:Perceived family influence on organizational identity}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xl}
      \toprule 
        & Interviewees \\
      \midrule
      Family influence as most important factor influencing OI & [14], [15] \\
      Family influence has great impact \newline on OI & [] \\
      Family influence can have impact \newline on OI & [] \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{wraptable}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

---

Edit regarding teh request in teh comments:

Instead of manually fiddeling around with the linespacing, I'd suggest the following:

`\usepackage{etoolbox}\AtBeginEnvironment{wraptable}{\singlespacing}` automatically resets the linespacing to singlespacing in every `wraptable` environment in your document. `\addlinespace` from the `booktabs` package can be used to add some vertical khite space in teh tabe where needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage, a4paper, oneside, headsepline]{scrreprt} % headsepline 

\usepackage{wrapfig} % Text fließt um Figure

\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption} %Tabellencaption linksbündig
\usepackage{threeparttable} %Tabellenüberschrift linksbündig an Tabelle
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{wraptable}{\singlespacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{wraptable}{r}{0.7\textwidth}

  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Perceived family influence on organizational identity}
    \label{table:Perceived family influence on organizational identity}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{6.5cm} p{2.5cm}}
      \toprule 
        & Interviewees \\
      \midrule
      Family influence as most important factor influencing OI & [14], [15] \\ \addlinespace
      Family influence has great impact \newline on OI & [] \\ \addlinespace
      Family influence can have impact \newline on OI & [] \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{wraptable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi leandris, thanks for helping out again! All 3 of your possible solutions work great. I do prefer the 2nd solution of table 0.1.

Comment: I do prefer the 2nd solution of table 0.1. The only thing I don't like is the evenly distributed spacing between the rows. I would like the the spacing between the line "Family influence as most important factor" and "influencing OI" to be smaller (like it is in your first 0.1 table). I used: \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4} and
\linespread{1} \selectfont \centering. This also worked. Thank You!

Comment: @LaTexNewbie: You're welcome. Regarding the linespacing in the table, please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

For very narrow columns, `\sloppy` is SOP.  You can turn if off between paragraphs using `\fussy`.

Most of these packages are irrelevant to this example, and should have been removed to create a Minimal example.

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage, a4paper, oneside, headsepline]{scrreprt} % headsepline 

\usepackage{scrhack} % verbessert einige Fremdpakete und das Zusammenspiel von einigen Paketen mit KOMA-Script
\usepackage{graphicx} % Graphiken einfügen
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Text fließt um Figure
\usepackage{caption} % Überschriften formatieren
\usepackage{booktabs} % Tabelle
\usepackage[section]{placeins} %Floatbarriere

\usepackage{multirow} %für Tabellen
\usepackage{makecell} %fette hline
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption} %Tabellencaption linksbündig
% \usepackage{floatrow} % Tabellencaption in wrapped umgebung

\usepackage{threeparttable} %Tabellenüberschrift linksbündig an Tabelle

\usepackage{caption} % doopelte hline
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\doubleRule{\toprule\toprule}
\newcommand\doublerule{\toprule\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{\doublerulesep}{0.95em}}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mytabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[mytabitem]{nosep,leftmargin=*,before=\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip},after=\vspace{-1\baselineskip}, label=\textbullet}
\newcommand{\tabitem}[1]{\begin{mytabitem}\item #1\end{mytabitem}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}% really?

\usepackage{blindtext}% MWE only
\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\tempbox}{% measure width
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm} p{2.5cm}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{~} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Interviewees}\\
\midrule
\vtop{\hbox{\strut Family influence as most important}\hbox{\strut factor influencing OI}} & [14], [15] \\
\vtop{\hbox{\strut Family influence has great impact}\hbox{\strut on OI}} & [] \\
\vtop{\hbox{\strut Family influence can have impact}\hbox{\strut on OI}} & [] \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}%
\begin{wraptable}{r}{\wd\tempbox}% use width of tabular
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7} % this reduces the vertical spacing between rows
\linespread{0.95} \selectfont \centering
% \ttabbox
\caption{Perceived family influence on organizational identity}
\label{table:Perceived family influence on organizational identity}
\usebox\tempbox
\end{wraptable}

\sloppy\blindtext
\end{document}
```